# How to run a jar file from Jmeter?

Tags: command-line, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I tried the following in the Bean Shell Sampler;

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c && cd /Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin & java -jar File-2.0-SNAPSHOT.WAR");
```

It looks like, it is not able to run.. Am i doing in the correct way?

Comment: there are many things wrong with this... to begin with you are trying to run WAR as JAR, which is weird; the path `/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin` cannot possibly work on windows and the whole format of cmd is not right. Did you check help for `cmd /c` ?

Comment: I got it working by using an OS Process Sampler. By adding Java as the command and -jar, {jar path} as the command parameters.@KirilS. Thanks for your response.

Comment: would you Please edit your question and provide the answer it worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it with Beanshell, I would suggest the following amendment to the process command line:

```
cmd /c start java -jar .....
```

See [cmd.exe documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) for more information

However in majority of cases it might be easier to use [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) which allows executing arbitrary commands and programs. Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)